# Error while loading Assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Came across the following error after publishing through Continuous Integration Server.

[image]

This issue got resolved as well after following this link 
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/45/posts/12032/failed-to-complete-setup-of-assembly-hr-0x8007000b-probing-terminated-windows7-64bit-solved.aspx

But need to understand the reason why this issue was happening.Have investigated a bit by going through this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx#switch_to_default

but was not able to understand the problem here. Therefore can anyone help me to understand this issue better.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sameer Ahmed.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/405f5bb5-87a3-43d2-8138-54b75db73aa1.mspx?mfr=true) link, 64bit windows cannot load 32bit DLLs. So we need to enable this in IIS so that it can create 32 bit worker processes.